# git push stalls on macOS

Tags: git, macos

after the last two updates of xcode I am having a really annoying problem with git.

All commands but `git push` works perfectly. But `git push` stalls/hangs. This is both in xcode, in terminal, and magit through emacs.
As can be seen in the picture below literally nothing happens.
Any ideas on what is wrong.
I have no clue how to provide a minimal working example for this.

It is across all my git repos, it is across gitlab, bitbucket, github, gitea, self hosted git-scm server, and more git repo services.
Sometimes a computer reboot fixes it for like an hour or so.

[image]

I tried `git push --verbose`
Which shows that `git` get stuck at or right after:

```
Pushing to gitlab.com:<PROJECT_URL>
```

**EDIT ["solved"]:** @torek said it might be clamshell affecting the wifi card due to heat distribution. I have now tried to run in none-clamshell mode for while and it seems to "solve" the issue.

Comment: try  git push --verbose. Maybe you could see more info.

Comment: Most Git commands work entirely locally: you get a complete copy of an entire repository (every commit ever) and from then on your computer never needs to reach out over the network—with two exceptions: when you want to *update* your repository *from* their repository, and when you want to send any new commits *you* made *to* their repository. The latter is `git push` and if it stalls like that, it usually means there's something wrong with your network setup. Consider monitoring network activity and/or using `tcpdump` to watch the push.

Comment: @torek clone and pull works no trouble what so ever

Comment: @Mate yeah that just gets to `Pushing to gitlab.com:<URL>` :/ it is flipping annoying

Comment: Once time I needed to push a *huge* pkg and set =>  git config http.postBuffer 524288000 . But I think it's not the case.  Do you have a proxy or VPN or similar open?

Comment: @Mate no, no vpn no nothing

Comment: That clone and pull work is why I suspect a network issue. :-) Seriously, it seems like your network can receive large packets, but not send them. Getting tcp traces from strategic points would tell you something. Perhaps there's a buggy thing sending your mac the wrong tcp mss, for instance. An overlarge tcp packet should undergo ip fragmentation and reassembly but perhaps that's administratively disabled somewhere, etc. It's hard to say without a lot of data and analysis.

Comment: @torek you mean the settings on the mac specifically or the overall network? For I can push from my Linux machines no problem :/

Comment: and I find it f... up weird that it came after an xcode update

Comment: Could be your wifi card too. One thing that's not clear is why rebooting *sometimes* fixes it for *some duration*, but that's a clue. Does it have something to do with DHCP? What else might be going on? Debugging networks is a standard network admin thing.

Comment: hmmmm I really hope this will not work.... I really hope

Comment: phew didn't work... I just realised that it also started happening after I started using the mac in clamshell mode XD

Comment: @torek how would I id if it is the wifi card?

Comment: Try using a hardwired ethernet (not sure what model mac you have but you can either use an adapter, or if it's really old, the ethernet connector). Clamshell mode might affect heat distribution, which might affect the wifi card.

Comment: @torek I will try a weird connection later today. When I get close to a plug XD but for now I will try and run in non clam shell mode and see what happens. A friend theorised that it might be the Bird process (i.e. iCloud upload) that is the problem

Comment: That seems possible: don't put a Git *repository* in an iCloud-synced folder as it will eventually break. (You can put the working tree in a synced folder, but I would not.)

Comment: @torek it is not in the icloud drive. But he has apparently experienced a problem with it before that bird gets priority